# "How to" question about initializing ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry if this question has already been answered (I couldn't find anything relevant), but how would I initialize a 3 dimensional array without using loops or hard-coding the values?

I want to create a 3-dim. array with shape (x,y,2) and initialize it so that the values in the third axis represent the indices for the first two axes. For example, [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]],[[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]]. I don't want to use loops to do it (although that would be very simple to do) because the actual dimensions would be quite large (it's for an image-processing application) and I want to avoid using loops wherever possible.

This is the obvious way:

```py
arr = np.empty((600,800,2))
for row in range(600):
    for col in range(800):
        arr[row,col] = [row,col]
```

Is there a more efficient, numpy-like way to do this?

Comment: there's absolutely a better way if you're using iteration in numpy. *continues reading question*

Comment: Thanks! You mean 'nditer'? I didn't even realize that existed, I had to google it to find out what you meant (I'm just learning numpy). I'm still trying to figure out how I'd use it, but would that be any more efficient than doing it the traditional Python way?

Comment: Ah oops, no, i just meant that avoid `for i in` whenever you're using numpy. numpy was designed to make use of vectorization, iterating over numpy arrays is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy has np.indices((rows, columns))

```
np.indices((800, 600)).shape
# (2, 800, 600)

res= np.indices((800, 600)).swapaxes(0,2).swapaxes(0,1)
res.shape
# (800, 600, 2)

%timeit np.indices((800, 600)).swapaxes(0,2).swapaxes(0,1)
# 6.77 ms ± 41.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit try3(800, 600)
# 24 ms ± 702 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Alternatively use np.moveaxis. My timings were the same as for the double swap axes.

```
np.moveaxis( np.indices((800, 600)), 0, 2)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Perhaps `np.rollaxis(np.indices((800, 600)), 0, 3)`?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem rollaxis is was my first thought but it throws a deprecated warning. The numpy docs say prefer moveaxis.

Comment: Thanks! This is even simpler than using 'mgrid' (and more self-explanatory, I think). But I'll time both and see if there's any difference.

Comment: Yes, np.indices seems to be faster than np.mgrid.  

    %timeit arr = np.indices((6000,8000),dtype=float64).swapaxes(0,2).swapaxes(0,1)  
    431 ms ± 2.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  
    
    %timeit arr = np.mgrid[0:6000,0:8000].transpose(1,2,0)  
    1.27 s ± 41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: `np.mgrid[0:6000,0:8000]` returns an array of ints.  `np.mgrid[0:6000,0:7999:8000j]` returns an array of floats.  8000 values across the range 0. to 7999. inclusive.  The timings were slower for float mgrid on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces (in a small case):

```
In [208]: arr = np.empty((3,4,2)) 
     ...: for row in range(3): 
     ...:     for col in range(4): 
     ...:         arr[row,col] = [row,col] 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [209]: arr                                                                                                
Out[209]: 
array([[[0., 0.],
        [0., 1.],
        [0., 2.],
        [0., 3.]],

       [[1., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 3.]],

       [[2., 0.],
        [2., 1.],
        [2., 2.],
        [2., 3.]]])
In [221]: arr.shape                                                                                          
Out[221]: (3, 4, 2)
```

`mgrid`, one of several functions to make grids, produces:

```
In [222]: np.mgrid[0:3,0:4]                                                                                  
Out[222]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]])
In [223]: _.shape                                                                                            
Out[223]: (2, 3, 4)
```

We can get `arr` by transposing this:

```
In [224]: np.mgrid[0:3,0:4].transpose(1,2,0).shape                                                           
Out[224]: (3, 4, 2)
```

`np.meshgrid` makes a similar result, but as a tuple of arrays.

A mix of `repeat` and `tile` on `np.arange(3)` and `np.arange(4)` could also be used.

```
np.reshape(list(np.ndindex(3,4)),(3,4,2)) 
np.reshape(list(itertools.product(range(3),range(4))),(3,4,2))
```

also works, though it may have similar speed to your code.
`

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to numpy, avoid iteration best you can. One possible approach here, you can use `arange` to construct a 1d array with all the numbers you will need upfront, and then use some numpy manipulations to get the desired output.

```
import numpy as np       
x = 600
y = 800
def try1(x, y):
    arr = np.empty((x,y,2))
    for row in range(x):
        for col in range(y):
            arr[row,col] = [row,col]
    return arr

def try2(x, y):
    temp = np.arange(x * y)
    outer = temp // y
    inner = temp % y
    out = np.dstack((outer, inner)).reshape(x, y, 2)
    return out

%timeit try1(x, y)
#489 ms ± 2.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit try2(x, y)
#10.6 ms ± 98.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Edit:

I also added hpaulj's mgrid answer and it's clearly better:

```
def try3(x, y):
    return np.mgrid[0:x,0:y].transpose(1,2,0)

%timeit try3(x, y)
#8.39 ms ± 43.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks again! That's even more concise than Eric's solution. I like one-line solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to achieve what you want using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty((600,800,2))
first_indices = np.repeat(np.arange(600).reshape(600, 1), 800, axis=1)
arr[:,:,0] = first_indices
second_indices = np.repeat(np.arange(800).reshape(800,1), 600, axis=1).T
arr[:,:,1] = second_indices
print(arr)
```

It is a bit concise, but np.arange creates the indices 0-599 and 0-799. These then have to be reshaped from shape (600,) and (800,) to shapes (600,1) and (800,1). I then use numpy.repeat to duplicate the array 800 and 600 times respectively, to achieve 2D arrays of shape (600, 800) and (800, 600). Finally, I transpose the latter to achieve two 2D arrays of shape (600, 800), the first with the indices of the rows and the second with the indices of the columns.

```
arr = np.empty((600,800,2))

# x_indices = [0 1 2 ... 597 598 599]
x_indices = np.arange(600)

# x_indices from shape (600,) to (600,1)
x_indices = x_indices.reshape(600,1)

# duplicate x_indices 800 times:
#              <-----------800------------->
# x_indices = [[  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]] ^
#             [[  1   1   1 ...   1   1   1]] |
#             [[  2   2   2 ...   2   2   2]] |
#             ...                            600
#             [[597 597 597 ... 597 597 597]] |
#             [[598 598 598 ... 598 598 598]] |
#             [[599 599 599 ... 599 599 599]] V
x_indices = np.repeat(x_indices, 800, axis=1)


# y_indices = [0 1 2 ... 797 798 799]
y_indices = np.arange(800)

# y_indices from shape (800,) to (800,1)
y_indices = y_indices.reshape(800,1)

# duplicate y_indices 600 times:
#              <-----------600------------->
# y_indices = [[  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]] ^
#             [[  1   1   1 ...   1   1   1]] |
#             [[  2   2   2 ...   2   2   2]] |
#             ...                            800
#             [[797 797 797 ... 797 797 797]] |
#             [[798 798 798 ... 798 798 798]] |
#             [[799 799 799 ... 799 799 799]] V
y_indices = np.repeat(y_indices, 600, axis=1)

# transpose y_indices
#              <---------800---------->
# y_indices = [[0 1 2 ... 797 798 799]] ^
#             [[0 1 2 ... 797 798 799]] |
#             [[0 1 2 ... 797 798 799]] |
#             ...                      600
#             [[0 1 2 ... 797 798 799]] |
#             [[0 1 2 ... 797 798 799]] |
#             [[0 1 2 ... 797 798 799]] V
y_indices = y_indices.T

arr[:,:,0] = x_indices
arr[:,:,1] = y_indices
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. It's going to take me a while to understand it, I'm just learning numpy, but conciseness and efficiency are what I'm looking for. I can encapsulate it in a function and pass it the number of rows and columns required to make it more general.

Comment: @David I've added a more descriptive version of what I was doing if you find it helpful.